# Schema Extension in Microsoft Graph Limited to Tenant Only?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Per https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview#permissions (section "Schema extensions lifetime", State "Available"): "The schema extension is available for use by all apps in any tenant. "

What is the reasoning to not allow limiting schema extensions to a single tenant only? (or did I miss the HowTo on this one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to limit this by not moving the schema to "Available" and leaving it in "InDevelopment".  The lifecycle is documented [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview#schema-extensions) under Schema Extensions Lifecycle.  However we are investigating some tighter controls around visibility (my tenant only, any tenant) and authorization for schema extensions and which apps can get/set schema extension properties.

Be interested to hear more about your scenarios and the kinds of controls you are thinking of.

Hope this helps,

Comment: My scenario is "principle of least surprise" - an app isn't multi-tenant by default either (I'd wager that most companies would be surprised that their internal schema extensions go "public" when they "productize" it)